# How to store table data through form?

Tags: php, laravel

I was trying to store some table data through a form. I'm not sure whether I could submit the value through the table because it doesn't have any input value. Can anyone suggest a way I can store multiple table row data in database?

```
  <form>
     <table class="table cart border">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Roll</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>490</td>
         </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td>499</td>
         </tr>
        </tbody>
       </table>
       </form>
```

Comment: Sounds like a job for JavaScript and an AJAX call

Comment: How is that table generated?

Answer (score 1):

Use form entities through table rows and provide each column with name array.
And then you can save data. This is the easiest way.

For example,

```
<form action="{{URL::to('store/table/data')}}" class="form-horizontal" method="POST" role="form">
     <table>
     <thead>
            <tr>
                 <th>columnA</th>
                 <th>columnB</th>
                 <th>columnC</th>
            </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
         <tr>
             <td><input name="columnA[]"></td>
             <td><input name="columnB[]"></td>
             <td><input name="columnC[]"></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td><input name="columnA[]"></td>
             <td><input name="columnB[]"></td>
             <td><input name="columnC[]"></td>
         </tr>
     </tbody>
     </table>
     <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

Now, When you submit form through request then save this like,

Route,

```
Route::post('store/table/data','Controller@store');
```

Function,

```
public function store(Request $request){

    foreach($request->columnA as $key=>$value){
        // Save values for column A as $value
        // for other you can use index of $key like $request->columnB[$key], $request->columnC[$key].
    }
}
```

Hope you understand.